# Is it possible to take individual index snapshot from a cluster in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

Am working on Elasticsearch snapshot and restore, i know while restoring we have option to restore entire cluster or else only the required index from the snapshot. But do we have the feature available which enable us to take only the snapshot of index needed from a cluster i couldn't see a support documents for this. hence ask here, please let me know if there is option.

regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can take a snapshot of a specific index. From the [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.0/modules-snapshots.html)

> By default a snapshot of all open and started indices in the cluster is created. This behavior can be changed by specifying the list of indices in the body of the snapshot request.
>
> `PUT /_snapshot/my_backup/snapshot_1
>   {
>     "indices": "index_1,index_2",
>     "ignore_unavailable": true,
>     "include_global_state": false
>   }`